# Uncaught Error: Class "Kreait\\Firebase\\Auth\\UserQuery" not found

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am using Firebase Admin SDK for Php.
I am trying to query users from the Authentication in firebase by using
the example given in the docs.

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Auth\UserQuery;

# Building a user query object
  $userQuery = UserQuery::all()
   ->sortedBy(UserQuery::FIELD_USER_EMAIL)
   ->inDescendingOrder()
   // ->inAscendingOrder() # this is the default
   ->withOffset(1)
   ->withLimit(499); # The maximum supported limit is 500

   # Using an array
   $userQuery = [
       'sortBy' => UserQuery::FIELD_USER_EMAIL,
       'order' => UserQuery::ORDER_DESC,
       'offset' => 1,
       'limit' => 499, # The maximum supported limit is 500
   ];
```

Now i am getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Kreait\Firebase\Auth\UserQuery" not found

According to the docs UserQuery is still available.

[Firebase Admin Sdk Php](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-management.html#query-users)

Iam using php 8.1.12

Please help.